# How to use a variable retrieved by a delegate in a different method within the same class it was declared

Tags: swift, delegation

I have two classes, A and B:
In a class A I have a variable that increments its value by one each time a certain condition is met. In class B, I want to be able to access the value from that variable which I have managed by implementing delegation (by implementing breakpoints, i can see that "valueRetrieved" is holding the right value).

My question is how would I be able to use valueRetrieved and return it as a int. I tried creating a different method and calling valueRetrieved but it I only get 0 as a value. The reason being is because I want that value to be linked to a UILabel in my ViewController. Any help would be appreciated, in case this is the wrong approach please let me know.

```
protocol valueDelegate: class {
    func retrieveValue -> Int    
}

class B {
    var valueRetrieved = 0
    var valueToIncrement = 0
    weak var delegate: valueDelegate?

    func callToValueRetrieved() {
        valueRetrieved = (self.delegate?.retrieveValue())!
        if valueRetrieved == 6{
            valueToIncrement += 1
        }

    func toUseValueIncremented -> Int{
        //would want to return the final valueToIncrement as a int here
return""
    }
```

Class A

```
class A: valueDelegate{
    func retrieveValue() -> Int {
        return valueToDelegate
    } 
}

var valueToDelegate:Int = 0
var bClass: B = B()

func ready() -> Bool {
    if //condition{
        valueToDelegate += 1
        bClass.delegate = self
        bClass.callToValueRetrieved()
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of protocol having retrieveValue() as function use variable as below

`protocol valueDelegate: class {
    var valueToDelegate: Int { get }
}`

Thus you can easily accesses variable as self.delegate.valueToDelegate and perhaps even update it.

Comment: how would I link valueToDelegate to valueRetrieved? because in class A I have the return call and I would need to change it to var retrieveValue:Int

Comment: Slight update, I figured it, just equalling valueToDelegate to the value. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it the other way around

```
protocol ValueDelegate: class {
    func didSetValue(value: Int)
}

class A {

    var valueToBeSent = 0
    weak var delegate: ValueDelegate?

    func ready() -> Bool {
        if true {
            valueToBeSent += 1
            delegate?.didSetValue(value: valueToBeSent)
            return true
        }
    }
}

class B: ValueDelegate {

    var valueToIncrement = 0

    func didSetValue(value: Int) {
        valueToIncrement = value
        print("value has changed: \(value)")
    }

    var myInstanceOfA = A()

    init() {
        myInstanceOfA.delegate = self
    }

    func testThatValueIsReturned() {
        // use the returned Bool as you intend to
        _ = myInstanceOfA.ready()
    }
}

var myInstanceOfB = B()

myInstanceOfB.testThatValueIsReturned() // value has changed: 1

myInstanceOfB.testThatValueIsReturned() // value has changed: 2
```

Comment: I have tried this method in a separate file and works perfectly as well! Thank you @Giorgio R.